# YAML::Dumper not quoting scalar string "-"

Tags: ruby, perl, yaml

Problem: Getting Perl's [`YAML::Dumper`](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML%3a%3aDumper) to emit `{key=>"-"}` as `key: "-"` rather than `key: -`

I'm processing hashes from database rows, reading them with SOAP and turning them into YAML for consumption by the next stage.

The first stage is written in Perl, and generates the YAML using `YAML::Dumper`.  Unfortunately, for keys that have a value of `"-"`, the bare hyphen is emitted *sans* any quoting:

```
$ perl -e 'use YAML;use YAML::Dumper; my $ydumper=YAML::Dumper->new(); print $ydumper->dump({key1=>1,key2=>"-",key3=>3});'
--- 
key1: 1
key2: -
key3: 3
```

The next stage, which reads the above and performs further manipulations on it, is in Ruby.  The raw dash causes Ruby's YAML parser to varf:

```
$ ruby -rubygems -ryaml -e 'YAML.load($stdin.read);'  # assume the above piped in
/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/psych.rb:205:in `parse': (<unknown>): block sequence entries are not allowed in this context at line 3 column 7 (Psych::SyntaxError)
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/psych.rb:205:in `parse_stream'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/psych.rb:153:in `parse'
    from /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/psych.rb:129:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

My question is simple: How can I instruct `YAML::Dumper` to emit the dash as a quoted string?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this part of the YAML spec? Seems like maybe a problem with the ruby implementation.

Comment: It looks as though it may, indeed, be a bug in Ruby's implementation.

http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2759963 says that block sequences begin with a **dash and a space**, whereas there is only a dash here -- no trailing space.

Comment: Did you try escaping it? like Double quotes inside single quotes. `'\"-\"'`

Comment: http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2788859 seems significant: "Plain scalars must not begin with most indicators, as this would cause ambiguity with other YAML constructs. However, the “:”, “?” and “-” indicators may be used as the first character if followed by a non-space “safe” character, as this causes no ambiguity." The Perl output is not followed by a "non-space “safe” character", so the problem seems to lie here.

Comment: Escaping it means manually frobbing the data coming from the database -- not optimal.  This aren't data I'm generating.  However, to work around this issue, manual frobbing is exactly what I've added -- but it's an ugly hack that I'd like to remove.

Comment: @theTinMan - so is this a bug in Ruby, because it's treating a dash-but-not-a-space as a block sequence introducer, or `YAML::Dumper` because it's not following the dash with a safe character?  (Assuming newline isn't considered safe.)  Or both?  Thanks!

Comment: It's a bug in YAML::Dumper. The value you're talking about is a scalar, a string or integer, which can't be a single, bare, `-` value or `- ` (dash + space). It has to have something else. It's a red-herring that Ruby's YAML returns a block exception, but that happens because `-` by itself, or `- ` (dash + space) defines a block. So, using a fixed version of YAML::Dump, or using YAML::XS, would fix the problem. This is discussed in the links provided by @snoopy in [his answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23898481/128421).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created a [pull request](https://github.com/ingydotnet/yaml-pm/pull/22) for YAML::Dumper on github, that hopefully gets accepted and fixes this problem.

Comment: Accepted and uploaded to CPAN by maintainers -  http://cpan.metacpan.org/authors/id/I/IN/INGY/YAML-0.91.tar.gz